# How do I make a pancake without egg?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, pancakes

I'm trying to make a basic pancake, with traditional texture, fluff, and taste, but without using eggs.  Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of pancakes are you thinking of? Swedish, korean, american, french, or..?

Comment: French and American

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple recipes for eggless pancakes online.  Most increase the amount of baking powder to help with the rise. Many use milk and butter, so they are not vegan.  If you are looking for a vegan recipe, those exist too.  They also tend to increase the baking powder, and often include non-dairy milk.  Whether or not they will sufficiently mimic the fluffiness of a traditional recipe is going to be completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually fine with dairy products, so the non-vegan version is fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Upon searching different websites, I found these options as the best egg-substitute (usually I use the forth option at home).

1. Applesauce
   Use a quarter cup of unsweetened applesauce in place of one egg in most baking recipes. Some sources say to mix it with half a teaspoon of baking powder. If all you have is sweetened applesauce, then simply reduce the amount of sugar in the recipe. Applesauce is also a popular healthy replacement for oil in many baked goods.
2. Banana
   Use a quarter cup of mashed banana (from about half a banana) instead of one egg when baking. Note that this may impart a mild banana flavor to whatever you are cooking, which could be a good thing.
3. Flaxseeds
   Heart-healthy flaxseeds can be used as an egg substitute. Mix one tablespoon of ground flaxseeds with three tablespoons of water until fully absorbed and viscous. Use in place of one egg. (You can use pre-ground flaxseeds or grind them yourself in a spice or coffee grinder.)
4. Water, oil, and Baking Powder
   Whisk together 2 tbspns water, 1 tspn oil (vegetable or corn oil), and 2 tspns baking powder. Use this in place of 1 egg.

You can review the  ([source website](https://www.sheknows.com/food-and-recipes/articles/955371/baking-without-eggs/)).

Answer (score 2):

I make (U.S.) pancakes often.  I rarely use an egg.  I use plain yogurt which I think gets more fluff out of the baking powder because it is sour.

Try

1.5 cups white flour

0.5 cup wheat flour

1 tbsp. baking powder

1 cup plain yogurt.  Not low fat!  Fatful yogurt.

Honey, approx. 2 tbsp.

Oil (I am using sunflower lately) approx. 1 tbsp.

Milk (whatever I have) to thin to pourable

No oil in the pan.